# How to ensure that buttons scale properly to different screen size in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview, uibutton

I am new to Swift and I am still struggling to find an easy way to make sure that my UI will scale properly based on screen size.
My UI is made of few buttons and labels and it was built on a iPhone 8 Plus screen. But now when I run it on smaller or bigger devices, the button are either not entirely visible or not centered.
How can I make sure that what I see on the iPhone 8 Plus is being scaled correctly to other devices? Any example I can follow?
I am using Xcode 12 and latest Swift version.

Comment: Use Autolayout.

Comment: Do you have any example I could replicate on xcode 12 and latest Swift version?